# file.open is not a function in node.js. file reading

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I'm trying to read a local text file (not over web). So, that I can parse it into a array. But I get the error: "file.open is not a function"

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var util = require('util');
var clients = [];
const fs = require('fs');
......................

/// read from file
var txtFile = "getData.txt"
let file = fs.readFileSync(txtFile, 'utf8');

file.open("r"); // open file with read access
var str = "";
while (!file.eof) {
    // read each line of text
    str += file.readln() + "\n";
}
file.close();
alert(str);
```

Comment: fs.readFileSync() has already read the file and closed it. Looks to me like you're trying to turn Javascript into C. RTFM.

Comment: `readFileSync` just returns a string. It already opened, read, and closed the file. There’s an `fs.open`, but it’s rare to need to use it directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`fs.readFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) reads the entire contents of a file and returns it as string.

This code:

```
var txtFile = "getData.txt"
let str = fs.readFileSync(txtFile, 'utf8');
alert(str);
```

is enough to put on screen the content of the file.

Read more about the [`fs` module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) of `node.js`.